# Cassandra cluster using docker

Tags: docker, cassandra, replication, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-cluster

I'm new to cassandra and wanted to understand and implement the NetworkTopology Stratergy.

I want to create a cassandra cluster with NetworkTopology stratergy with multiple data centers. How to do it?

I tried creating a docker bridge network and three cassandra nodes: cas1, cas2, cas3. When used nodetools to check status a cluster with single datacentre is only getting created. But I want to create 2 datacenters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a document which walks you through this: [Initializing a multiple node cluster (multiple datacenters)](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.x/cassandra/initialize/initMultipleDS.html).  It's for Cassandra 3.x, but the procedure is pretty much the same for 4.x as well.

But if I had to guess, I'd say there's two things you're probably missing:

In the `cassandra.yaml` set the `endpoint_snitch` to `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch`.

```
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

That tells Cassandra to check the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file for data center and rack information.  Inside that file, you'll find the following settings (by default).

```
dc=dc1
rack=rack1
```

This is where you can set the name of the new DC.  Then you can use those data center names to specify replication on keyspaces using `NetworkTopologyStrategy`.